# I have to solve for Tableau performance with about 30 million data points

Tags: optimization, hive, tableau-desktop

I have a use case where I need to have a structured data (with 30 million records & 20 columns) in a Tableau compatible source. And we want the tableau charts refresh to happen within 1sec of time. NOTE: That 30 million records are already aggregated so we cannot reduce the records further.
I was thinking about having a hive table & create a presto connection to create a tableau extract. But when I did that then I saw we have a latency of about 5-10 seconds.

Someone please help in selecting (may be) a better source along with (may be) a live tableau connection to refresh the data faster?

I was thinking about having a hive table & create a presto connection to create a tableau extract. But when I did that then I saw we have a latency of about 5-10 seconds.

Comment: Hopefully you are not planning a scatter plot... ?  for reference, a 4K UHD monitor has about 8M pixels.  It is somewhat nonsensical to plot 30M points on a chart.  Can you pre-process a heat map or histogram?

Comment: @AirSquid: Definitely not that.. But the use case is that, we have multiple Global filters on that 30 million data and at a time, we are not showing more than 150 rows in dashboard.
I hope the context helps!